# How to set as default value a variable in a prop in Vue.Js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a question. I need to set a prop with a default value that is obtained from a getter.

```
props: {
    userID: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    }
  }
```

The value that I want to set as default value is obtained with:

```
computed: {
    ...mapGetters('Auth', ['getId']),

}
```

How can I make the prop `UserID` have as default value the `getId` that is obtained from the mapGetter?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `computed` property for setting the default value.

```
computed: {
  userIdComp() {
    return this.userID ?? this.$store.getters['Auth/getId'];
  }
}
```

And use `userIdComp` instead of `userID`